# Java Frame setSize, setLocation not working

Tags: java, swing, jframe, calculator

[image]

These methods are not popped up while creating the object (`ctrl + spacebar`). Do I have to add any other package for this to work??

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] read [ask] and post a proper [mre] that demonstrates your issue. Otherwise with images of code we cannot copy-paste the code into our IDEs and test

Comment: This is more a question of how to use your to get method suggestions? Is this eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to add any other package for this to work?

No. They are methods inherited from parent classes that should not be used by programmers. Instead, [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) should use them.

### Edit

I'd thought this was to do with component size and location *within* a frame. It was only after looking more closely at the (horrible(1)) pictures of the screen I realised they were methods related to a `JFrame`, which changes the answer slightly.

1. `setSize(..)` should be not used, but `pack()` should. The former is no better than a guess, while the latter (called after components are added via layouts) will produce the correct size).
2. `setLocation(..)` is also less than optimal. `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` will center a packed frame on-screen, while `setLocationByPlatform(true)` (which I prefer) will place the app. in the position (determined by the OS) for the 'next' application (usually they will be stacked and offset slightly).

Coming back to the (1) note above:

1. Don't take pictures of a computer screen. All OS offer the ability to create a screenshot of either the current screen or the current app. In Windows that would be <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> for the entire screen or <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> for the focused app.

Comment: Both `setSize` and `setLocation` can be used by programmers on JFrame and usually used.

Comment: @DakshinamurthyKarra See edit to answer. *"..and usually used"* There are plenty of things commonly done by programmers that they shouldn't do, and that applies here as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is about eclipse's content assist, right?
If so, then please look at Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Appearance -> Type Filters. If there java.awt.* is selected, then methods of Component like setSize and setLocation are not shown.

Comment: The problem was introduced in Eclipse 2021-09 and removed in 2021-12. See [Eclipse 2021-12 Improvements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3W9bvidcO20&t=173s).